# Tracking Web Page using java,JS,Jquery,AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, tracking

I am fresher in this tracking web page topic.
I want to be write code for tracking web page and if is any changes have occurred in that page then it is able to automatic mail sending to my mail id.

Is it possible?
If yes then which programming language is best for it?
would you please give me suggestion that which technology I have used for this?
Which are prerequisites for it?
How do I've start and from where?
Give me basic example also.

Answer (score 0):

Which programming languages do you already know? Take the one you know the best!

Just to give an idea how to approach it:

- use a Library similar to jQuery (jquery, jsoup, beautifulsoup, etc…) to extract specific page elements
- save the element's content somewhere (database, file)
- run the script periodically
- compare saved content with fresh content from the website
- send a mail if a change happened

Comment: nice idea......I did this already but I don't want to be execute script periodically...I know java language.